# Django converts value to tuple after model-field updating

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm using Django 2.0. I have a model with a field declared as:

```
px = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

After getting an instance of this object from database, I try to update its property with:

```
obj.px = "-2.6"
```

The value "-2.6" comes from a variable, but I've tested with hard code: -2.6, 2.6, decimal.Decimal("-2.6"), etc. It always converts that value to a tuple I don't know why. What I get in django result is:

> argument must be a sequence of length 3

Django raises this error when calling the "save" method from the model, and it internally does the conversion:

```
            return decimal.Decimal(value)
```

When I print the new value of "px" I get this:

> (2.6,)

The only fix that I did was the following:

```
if isinstance(obj.px, tuple):
    obj.px = obj.px[0]
```

Comment: You mentioned that an error is being raised on the model's save method. Can you post the method?

Comment: Hi @Martey, with the "save" method I meant the default save method for Django (the one coming in django.db.models.Model). I don't have a custom "save" method

Answer (score 13):

I'm so sorry, I had an syntax error. I had code like:

```
obj.px = variable1,
obj.py = variable2,
```

So the problem is the comma at the end, python was taking the command as tuple I guess. I removed those commnas and all is wotking right. (I want to kill myself jeje)

Comment: It's a good idea to post snippets of the actual source code when asking questions. In cases like this, it can be the only way that someone else could figure out the problem.